# C++ SFML 2.2 vectors

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm just playing around with C++ SFML stuff and I kinda don't understand why my code isn't working. The thing I want to do is to draw like let's say 5, squares in Window randomly placed around the screen using vector, but I don't understand why it's not working.

This is the main game class:

```
#include "main_game.h"
#include "main_menu.h"

void main_game::Initialize(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    this->Player = new player();
    this->Player->setOrigin(this->Player->getGlobalBounds().width / 2, this->Player->getGlobalBounds().height / 2);

    this->TestObject = new testObject();
    this->TestObject->Initialize();
    this->TestObject->setOrigin(this->TestObject->getGlobalBounds().width / 2, this->TestObject->getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
}

void main_game::Update(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    this->Player->setPosition(sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window).x, sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window).y);
    this->Player->Update();

    if (this->Player->CheckCollision(TestObject))
    {
        this->TestObject->setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    }
    else
    {
        this->TestObject->setColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Escape))
    {
        coreState.SetState(new main_menu());
    }
}

void main_game::Render(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites)
{
    this->TestObject->Render(*window, sprites);

    window->draw(*this->Player);
}

void main_game::Destroy(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    delete this->Player;
    delete this->TestObject;
}
```

This is the testObject.h class

```
#pragma once

#include "entity.h"

class testObject : public Entity
{
public:
    testObject();
    void Initialize();
    void Render(sf::RenderWindow window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites);
    void Update();
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
};
```

And this is testObject.cpp class

```
#include "testObject.h"

testObject::testObject()
{
    this->Load("testObject.png");
}

void testObject::Initialize()
{
    sf::Texture testObjectTexture;
    sf::Sprite testObjectSprite;

    testObjectTexture.loadFromFile("testObject.png");
    testObjectSprite.setTexture(testObjectTexture);

    std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites(5, sf::Sprite(testObjectSprite));

    srand(time(0));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++)
    {
        sprites[i].setPosition(1 + (rand() % 1024 - 32), rand() % 640 - 32);
    }
}

void testObject::Render(sf::RenderWindow window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++)
    {
        window.draw(sprites[i]);
    }
}

void testObject::Update()
{
    Entity::Update();
}
```

The error message is

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Blahblah, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  testObject.cpp
1>d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\blahblah\testobject.cpp(18): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\blahblah\testobject.cpp(22): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>  main_game.cpp
1>d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\blahblah\main_game.cpp(16): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\3rdpartylibs\include\sfml\window\window.hpp(521): error C2248: 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'sf::NonCopyable'
1>          d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\3rdpartylibs\include\sfml\system\noncopyable.hpp(67) : see declaration of 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable'
1>          d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\3rdpartylibs\include\sfml\system\noncopyable.hpp(42) : see declaration of 'sf::NonCopyable'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'sf::Window::Window(const sf::Window &)'
1>d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\3rdpartylibs\include\sfml\graphics\rendertarget.hpp(419): error C2248: 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'sf::NonCopyable'
1>          d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\3rdpartylibs\include\sfml\system\noncopyable.hpp(67) : see declaration of 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable'
1>          d:\visual studio projects\blahblah\3rdpartylibs\include\sfml\system\noncopyable.hpp(42) : see declaration of 'sf::NonCopyable'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'sf::RenderTarget::RenderTarget(const sf::RenderTarget &)'
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please be a little more descriptive of your problem than *"I don't understand why it's not working"*

Comment: Basically I did try to draw multiple objects with vector on brand new project with only main.cpp in main(), and it worked like a charm. But the problem here is probably I can't do it right between the classes and multiple functions.

Comment: I rather meant for you to describe what you mean by *"it's not working"*. Is it a compiler error? If so, what's the error message? Or is it a runtime error? If so, what is actually happening, and how does it differ from your expectations of what should happen?

Comment: Oh I forgot to put in error :D.

Comment: It just build error that it is giving me.

Answer (score 0):

This specific error, (although I'm pretty sure you will have more once you fix it), probably comes from this:

```
void testObject::Render(sf::RenderWindow window, std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites)
```

You are passing the `RenderWindow` by value, but it is non-copyable. Pass it by reference or pointer instead.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that problem, but now it's not giving me any errors, so that's good, but it is not rendering anything.

Comment: @KuziNs: That's a completely different problem. It belongs in a different post.

Comment: The reason your sprites aren't displaying is because that have been unloaded, you need to create a constant array/vector/map which will store the textures and then in your other objects set a reference to the texture and then set up your sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed that problem, but now it's not giving me any errors, so that's good, but it is not rendering anything.

```
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Visual Studio Projects\Blahblah\Debug\Blahblah.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Visual Studio Projects\Blahblah\Blahblah\sfml-graphics-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Visual Studio Projects\Blahblah\Blahblah\sfml-system-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\Visual Studio Projects\Blahblah\Blahblah\sfml-window-d-2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Blahblah.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You should edit your question if you want to update it. Also, the messages you posted don't indicate any errors - they just tell you there's no debugging symbols available for system libraries - which is completely normal.